# Задача «Степень»

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, олимпиада, теория-чисел

Всем здравствуйте! Столкнулся с такой задачей:

**Условие:**
Для того чтобы проверить, как её ученики умеют считать, Мария Ивановна каждый год задаёт им на дом одну и ту же задачу — для заданного натурального  найти минимальное натуральное  такое, что  в степени  (, умноженное на себя  раз) делится на . От года к году и от ученика к ученику меняется только число . 
Вы решили помочь будущим поколениям. Для этого вам необходимо написать программу, решающую эту задачу.

**Входные данные:**
Во входном файле содержится единственное число  (`1 ≤  ≤ 10^9`) — на всякий случай; вдруг Мария Ивановна задаст большое число, чтобы «завалить» кого-нибудь…).

**Выходные данные:**
Вывести единственное число .

**Примеры:**
*Ввод 1:*

```
8
```

*Вывод 1:*

```
4
```

*Ввод 2:*

```
1
```

*Вывод 2:*

```
1
```

Долго пытался решить задачу. **Мой код с описаниями:**

```
Python

from sys import setrecursionlimit
setrecursionlimit(10**9) # увеличение максимальной глубины рекурсии

def fast_pow(a, n): # функция быстрого возведения в степень
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    elif n == 1:
        return a
    elif n % 2 != 0:
        return a * fast_pow(a, n-1)
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return fast_pow(a*a, n/2)

def decomp(n): # функция разложения числа на простые множители
    ans = []
    d = 2
    while d * d <= n:
        if n % d == 0:
            ans.append(d)
            n //= d
        else:
            d += 1
    if n > 1:
        ans.append(n)
    return ans



x = int(input())
a = list(set(decomp(x))) # разложение числа x на простые множители в единственном экземпляре
b = decomp(x) # разложение числа x на простые множители

y = 1
for i in range(len(a)): # перемножение простых множителей
    y *= a[i]
k = 1
n = k*y

if x == 1: # если x = 1, то и n = 1
    print(1)
elif len(b) >= 29: # 29 - потому что хотя бы 2**30 уже будет более 10**9, что противоречит условию задачи
    print(y) # тогда y**y уже будет делится на n
else:
    while pow(n,n,x) != 0:
        n = k*y
        k += 1
    print(n)
```

Программа не проходит последний тест проверки. Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибки в коде.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108913/discussion-on-question-by-daniil-savinov--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо:

```
if x == 1: # если x = 1, то и n = 1
    print(1)
elif len(b) >= 29: # 29 - потому что хотя бы 2**30 уже будет более 10**9, что противоречит условию задачи
    print(y) # тогда y**y уже будет делится на n
else:
    while k != n//y: # n = k*y, где k - любое натуральное число
        n = k*y
        if fast_pow(n,n) % x == 0:
            print(n)
            break
        k+=1
```

Используйте вот это:

```
if a[0] != x:
    for i in range(40):
        if fast_pow(((i+1) * y), ((i+1) * y)) % x == 0:
            print((i+1) * y)
            break
else:
    print(a[0])
```

P.S. Как в комментариях было сказано, лучше используйте встроенный `pow` вместо `fast_pow`

Answer (score 0):

```
elif len(b) >= 29:
    print(y)
```

Измени константу на 30 и все тесты пройдешь